# Flow to get all site collections in a tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-flow

Created a Flow by using the below REST call and stored the title and Urls in another list

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_
SITES_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS')/items?$select=Title,SiteUrl
```

Here the problem is it is returning only 100 items but I have 360 site sollections.

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed default behaviour. SP by default will return 100 items.

If you want more than 100 items, you need to specify that using `$top` param.

So you can append, for example, `$top=1000` to the endpoint.

Modify the endpoint as below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_
SITES_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS')/items?$select=Title,SiteUrl&$top=1000
```

This will fetch you the first 1000 items. You can do this upto 5000 items.

If there are >5000 items, you will need to implement paging.

Reference - [Page through returned items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#sort-returned-items)

[How to get more than 5000 items from SharePoint Online in Flow](https://alextofan.com/2019/08/22/how-to-get-more-than-5000-item-from-sharepoint-online-in-flow/#:~:text=5000%20items%20limit&text=The%20maximum%20top%20count%20you,than%20100%20items%20are%20retrieved.)